# Regex - Get every part of a string except the middle of it

Tags: c, regex

I have the following function declaration:

```
typedef size_t(__cdecl *pfn_fwrite_t)(const void *restrict buffer, size_t size, size_t count, FILE *restrict stream);
```

What would be a regex pattern that would give me all parts except of: "pfn_fwrite_t"

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Somehow along

```
^(\w+\s+\w+\(\w+\s+\*)\w+(\).*)$
```

retrieving both matches: [RegEx101](http://regex101.com/r/dB4tN9/1)